# Is master-slave replication my best setup?

Tags: postgresql, master-slave

I have a big database which writes 1Gb each day. This runs on a low-cost node with just a couple of cores and few Gb memory.

Once or twice per week for a couple of hours, I read from the db and analyse the data.

I wish to pay hourly for the 16vCPU / 64Gb ram node on which to perform these large db reads and computationally intensive analysis.

I seem to require two instances of my database, so as not to have any downtime. (Pausing the write scripts and unmounting the DB volume / mounting it to a high-spec node for 2 hrs is to be avoided.)

My idea is the have master-slave setup, where the master has 100% up-time and it streams to the slave, which is on a volume I unmount weekly for a few hours of analysis.

If the slave is unreachable for a few hours, will this cause problems?

Have I overlooked a superior setup?

Comment: Maybe I just need rsync on a cron job across the directories? Is this a bad idea for large directories?

Comment: if you have enough `wal_keep_segments` to include data for two hours, or have configured `archive_command`, `restore_command ` and have enough space to keep wals - solution seems ok to me. well - maybe instead of replication all the time, you could just do pg_basebackup to big machine and spin up replication every time  looks cheap to me (one command)

Comment: Thanks. What are the advantages of this over simply using rsync?

Comment: oh.I don't remember already the sequence that pg_basebackup performs, but it is very close to what rsync does of course. In my experience rsynced copies fail to spin up replication (especially 9.2, 9.3) every third, fourth time, while pg_baseebackup - none so far.

Comment: do you mean data corruption occurs and prevents db access in the target directory? Now I'm scared :/

Comment: yes, despite rsync is atomic, I have had problems with it multiple times

Comment: If your master is "big" (how big? many terabytes?) then rebuilding a hot standby regularly is probably not what you want. As @VaoTsun said, if you have `wal_keep_segments` set high enough on the master (or in recent versions of Postgres, `replication slots`), then taking the replica down occasionally should be fine. When you unmount the replica's volume, do you mean "analysis" on the master?

Comment: My entire DB is around 500Gb. I have got rsync working, it only took about 20 minutes to sync the entire db into a new empty volume. Because this is a small amount of time, I won't even have the secondary volume mounted most of the time; I will just mount it to sync for analysis.

But now I'm worried that this "easy" method will run into problems, after Vao Tsun's responses about issues with rsync. Which I choose out of rsync and pg_basebackup, it is now clear I will only perform the sync once per week, and have the volume detached most the time.

Comment: rsync is generally only useful these days when you a quiescent master and replica and you are merging only the deltas. pg_basebackup is the typical method to rebuild a replica, and you'll only have problems if the process is executed incorrectly. If doing it via rsync and the master/replica are running, you must use start_backup/stop_backup commands. I'd advise looking at a tool like [pgbackrest](http://pgbackrest.org/) before attempting to do the rebuilds manually.

Comment: If something goes wrong, is it an all or nothing? Does the fact that it appeared to work and I can connect to my database in the destination volume indicate every block has been perfectly transferred? Or are we talking about 0.001% of rows being absent in destination, or something else?

Comment: no - that is the rsync problem I've met. after rsync copying without warning I periodically hit corrupted block when `pg_dumpall` (which is allgood untill you meet it). but observed it only on 9.3 of course with proper backup start. I could make some stupid mistake of course or hit the bug. I could not spend time investigating the case - just swithced to pg_basebackup, especially after reading it is frendly to copy data from slave